# rerouting in views MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have in my views dir two folders: nl and eng. In every dir there is a home, account.
One in dutch and 1 in english.
But how can I route default to nl-pages and by clicking to a link using the eng-pages.
Then I want to use cookies to set default to a languages.

thanks in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you going through the [following guide](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html).

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of the resx files. I don't want to use them, but on seo prospective I want to use just 'ordinary' views.  Thanks anyway!!

Comment: @1SeoAdvies, you may checkout the following blog post: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx which illustrate show to use different views based on the User-Agent. It's for mobile site but you can tweak it to use the language cookie in order to render the view in the proper directory. But having different views for each language seems like an overkill. Not sure exactly what is your scenario but resource files might be a better way to localize a web application.

Comment: Thanks That's the one I was looking for.. Cheers