# filling dropdownlist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I need to fill a dropdownlist with values from a settings table in a database.

(id int, code string, description string, value string)
 1     , 1          , "something"       ,  "This1"
 2     , 1          , "this too"        ,  "This2"
 3     , 2          , "something else"  ,  "This2"
 n     , x          , and so on.......

Now I only want to fill the dropdownlist with code 1 (I want to use this on a lot of pages.)

How can I do this?? url to a tutorial or something like is also ok!
btw I am using mvc3.
cheers

Comment: What kind of table?  Database table?

Comment: And what is your point?? It doesnot matter to me! I only want some answer to my question(s). Most answers are not relevant!

Comment: @1SeoAdvies, I don't agree that most answers are not relevant. Here's an [example of one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329288/rerouting-in-views-mvc3/6329342#6329342) in which you said that it helped you and yet it is not marked as answer.

Comment: @1SeoAdvies - you should be flagged, tagged and bagged!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If regular dropdown than as below

```
 using (DBContext context = new DBContext())
        {
            dropdown1.DataSource = context.settings .ToList();
            dropdown1.DataTextField = "code";
            dropdown1.DataValueField = "id";
            dropdown1.DataBind();
        }
```

If using MVC ?

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2124ae/5628/

[Create a Dropdown List for MVC3 using Entity Framework (.edmx Model) & Razor Views && Insert A Database Record to Multiple Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326515/create-a-dropdown-list-for-mvc3-using-entity-framework-edmx-model-razor-view)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it across multiple pages, you want to also look in to Partial Views:

http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/
http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/05/ASPNETMVC3TutorialsIndex.aspx

Comment: I know how to make a partial view. thanks anyway! But I want to know how to fill the dropdownlistfor!

Comment: @1SeoAdvies - Sorry, I thought your statement "I want to use this on a lot of pages" was an inquiry, not a statement.

Comment: @1SeoAdvies - just joking around that's all :)